# How to trace and debug a hanging apache process

Tags: php, mysql, apache, trace, dtrace

I have a problem with my PHP backend I can't figure out. I experience intermittent "hanging" of some apache processes when requesting the API (PHP code returning json).

Apache never fails to deliver files (html, css, js etc.), it's just a limited number of API calls that trigger the problem. The request stands as pending in Chrome dev tools "Network" tab, and even if I run `apachectl restart` the requests are still pending after restart. I can see that all `httpd` processes doesn't stop when I run `apachectl stop`. I have to kill them with `killall -9 httpd`.

When the problem occurs, I have to stop Apache, kill all httpd processes, and start apache again. If I don't restart most API calls hang (probably the ones assigned to the hanging child-processes).

The API calls that trigger the problem all include calls to MySQL.

Checking the processlist on the mysql server, the connections are established but in a state of SLEEP.

Does the problem sound like a code-problem or configuration-problem?

The error logs (mysql and apache) doesn't show anything, so I guess I should try to `strace` (`dtruss` on mac?) the apache process. **How do I do that?**

--

*Environment:*

- OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite
- Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) *- Installed with os x*
- MySQL 5.6.22 (Homebrew) *- innodb, mysqli interface, non-persistent connections*
- PHP 5.6.5 (Homebrew) *- php56, mcrypt, php56-mcrypt, php56-apcu, php56-xdebug*